# How to delete a <div> in JS using a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">LiveChat <a href="#RESETlivechat&ERR_4F0" class="close-div">Close</a></div>
  <iframe class="live" src="https://tlk.io/friv432" width="400" height="400">TROUBLE LOADING LIVECHAT... ERR_4F0</iframe>
</div>
```

And I wan't to delete the #mydiv using the **CLOSE BUTTON** in the #mydivheader eventually it will end up destroying it self. I read many other articles but none worked for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete and element from the DOM using JavaScript by `Element.remove()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

In your case, you'll want to get a reference to the element `mydiv` and then `.remove()` that node once `mydivheader` is clicked.

Example:

```js
const divHeader = document.getElementById('mydivheader');
divHeader.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
  if (div) {
    div.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">LiveChat <a href="#RESETlivechat&ERR_4F0" class="close-div">Close</a></div>
  <iframe class="live" src="https://tlk.io/friv432" width="400" height="400">TROUBLE LOADING LIVECHAT... ERR_4F0</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("rmv").remove()
})
```

```html
<div id="rmv">Remove Me!</div>
<button id="btn">Click to remove</button>
```

Comment: Is it a problem that his close button is inside the DIV that has drag-and-drop enabled?

Comment: Could you revise your snippet to use his actual HTML and JS?